# COMException in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, com

in my application i am using a third party tool for recording the audio. it is working fine in local system. when i place my project in server i got this error...

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {3387A365-D5A3-4BEE-8095-C5CFD9ABE517} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {3387A365-D5A3-4BEE-8095-C5CFD9ABE517} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

Comment: Do you want to record the audio from the server or from the user's computer?

Comment: Your code can only record on the server.  To record from the client computer, you'll need to use Flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your COM component is not installed on the server.

You need to install it using `regsvr32` or its installer program.

Comment: how can i do this regsvr32,can u suggest me the process

Comment: What server is it? Do you have administrative RDP or console access? Do you know how COM works? What DLL is it?

Comment: we are recording from user's microphone and saving it in our sever it is our company server only(server window 2003 server)

Comment: The COM component on the server will record from the server's microphone.  It cannot record from the user's microphone.  You apparently need to learn the basics of HTTP and client-server programming.

Comment: we  have used a third party audio control to record an audio and storing it in our computer,It works fine for me on my local machine.But while iam uploading all the files on production server its throwing an error 
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {3387A365-D5A3-4BEE-8095-C5CFD9ABE517} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

Comment: sorry after upload all the files to the server and run the page, then it is showing this error

Comment: You're getting the error because the COM component is not installed on the server.  If you fix the error (by installing it on the server), you'll find that your website doesn't work because you're recording audio on the server, not the client.

Comment: ok then what is the solution for this problem, do you have any tool to record the audio or any reference.

Comment: i have a doubt, what is difference that when i recording the audio on server or on the client

Comment: When you visit a website, there are two different machines involved - the _server_ and the _client_.  The client is (usually) a regular computer in front of a human being.  The server is a big, powerful machine in a server room.  Your ASP.Net code, and your COM component, run on the server.  They have no direct access to the client machine, nor to its microphone.  Using the COM component on the server will record audio from the server's microphone (if it has one), in the server room.

Comment: ya i know this. when user record the audio (from client machine) and the audio file is store in the server only.

Comment: Your COM component doesn't run on the client machine.  _You are not recording anything on the client's machine_.

Comment: ya my tool is installed on server and user will record the audio from the client automatically it is saved in server

Comment: Unless the tool communicates out-of-band with a separate program that runs in the background on every client machine, that's not possible.  What tool is it?

Comment: Your tool is called Active Audio Record.  It records audio on the machine that it runs on.  Since it's running on the server, _it will not record anything on from client_.

Comment: my tool is audioctl for recording the audio

Comment: ok can u explain me how can install the tool in my server. it is giving the error. if it is fix i will check whether it is work or not i will check and inform you.

Comment: The same way you installed it on your computer.

Comment: You can check whether it works by browsing the current dev site from a different computer in a different room.  (not `localhost`)

Comment: ok thank you for great support Mr. SLaks, u spend valid time with me

Comment: ya i installed in server but it is giving same error Mr. Slaks